# from selenium import webdriver not working?

Tags: python, selenium, python-2.7, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

I downloaded the Selenium Python package including server, but I get an error:

```
File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: cannot import name webdriver
```

Comment: Did you actually install the package?  Do you use pip or easyinstall?

Answer (score 2):

There are two versions of Selenium. There is a Java server, which you can interface with Python using `Selenium RC`, and there is a newer `Selenium Webdriver` with which you can write stand-alone scripts (without running the Java server)

It sounds like you might have downloaded the `Selenium RC`, but not `Selenium Webdriver`. For `from selenium import webdriver` to work, you must install `Selenium Webdriver`.

To do that run

```
pip install -U selenium
```

Comment: Did not fix my problem either, and I had this working previously.